# Toolbar hidden by noification pannel

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apk, toolbar

so i've generated the apk, but when i start my app, the toolbar is hidder by the noification pannel:
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

[image]

Toolbar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50px"
    android:background="#263355"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/main_toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="package" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_solutis"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Splashscreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACCUEIL" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

values/style.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    </style>

</resources>
```

values-v19:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I'm on HTC One device, but if think its not by whats device i use...

Comment: obviously you use wrong Theme ...

Comment: @Selvin why the theme is wrong ? And so what i should use ?

Comment: Show your androidmanifest.xml and style.xml (all if you have several)

Comment: You might want to have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20167755/transparent-status-bar-system-ui-on-4-4-kit-kat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should remove this line:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```